# Recibir un Post con AngularJS en el $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una página web con angularJS (1.0) y una serie de rutas, necesito que para acceder a la página "x" sea mediante un post:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('pagWeb')
        .config(['$translateProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($translateProvider, $routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/politica-de-privacidad', {
                    title: 'Política de privacidad',
                    templateUrl: 'http...'
                })...
```

Sólo consigo hacer que cuando pongo en mi página "miWeb/politica-de-privacidad" vaya a la página, pero el problema es que esto es un get. Necesito que detecte el $routeProvider que es un post y sacar el dato que tenga.

Estoy mirando varias webs
https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Pero no encuentro lo que quiero hacer, ¿ acaso no se puede hacer?.

Gracias

**Edito**:

Código del controlador:

```
angular.module('crl').controller('ok', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$cookies', '$routeParams', '$window', '$location', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $cookies, $routeParams, $window, $location) {

}
```

La template URL trae impreso en el html al controlador que tiene que llamar:

**Edito2.**

La necesidad radica en que para mostrar la página del angularJS está

```
.when('/politica-de-privacidad/valor1/valor2/valor3'
```

Estos valores pueden ser interceptados y cambiarlos como se quiera.

Por eso se necesita llamar a la página de "politica de privacidad por medio del POST, para obtener esos datos por debajo."

Porque en el angularJS se coge de la ruta del navegador el valor1 y se pinta en el html con ese valor.

Tengo un servicio web en SpringBoot que llama por GET a
String url = http ---- /politica-de-privacidad/valor1/valor2/valor3

Entonces se puede "falsear" la llamada del servicio web y simplemente cambiar los valores a MANO en el navegador y obtener diferentes resultados.

```
if(($routeParams.valor1) == null){
            self.valor1= " "; 
        }else{
            self.valor1= ($routeParams.valor1).split("+").join(" ");
        }
```

De esta manera puedo coger los datos del navegador y pintarlos en el html, con el inconveniente que alguien puede tocarlos a mano y alterar el resultado, por eso la necesidad de llamar al AngularJS por post.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de tù controlador, probablemente tenga un método que se ejecute primeramente el cual es un get.

Comment: Ya está el código.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de tú controlador puedes crear un método a que se a ejecutar inicialmente `init` dentro de éste agregas tú llamada POST para obtener los datos que necesitas para tú pagina, desde la versión 1.5 de AngularJs puedes utilizar el método `OnInit` del controlador o componente.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.nombre = '';

  var init = function () {
  //Agregas tú llamada Post
    $scope.nombre = "Juan"
  }

//Método a ejecutarse iniialmente
  init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   Hola, {{nombre}}!
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Saludos cjara, el controlador NO tiene que lanzar la llamada POST, el controlador ha tenido que ser llamado por POST, el controlador, el routerProvider, etc.

Comment: Para entender mejor, ¿Cuál seria la necesidad de hacer eso? Obtener un archivos.js por POST?

Comment: Ya tienes modificado el post para lo que me preguntas.  muchas gracias!